# Change Icon of toggle button flutter

Tags: flutter, button, dart

Is there anyway to change icon of the toggle button on pressed or Is there anyway to make icon button function like toggle button?

I've tried following method but I want to change Icon agian to first one if the button pressed agian.

```
IconButton( iconSize: 30.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:4,right:4,top:0),
            icon: Padding(
            child: pressed ==true ? 
            Icon(Icons.start):Icon(Icons.stop)
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      pressed=true;
                    });
                  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IconButton( iconSize: 30.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:4,right:4,top:0),
        icon: Padding(
        child: pressed ==true ? 
        Icon(Icons.start):Icon(Icons.stop)
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  pressed = !pressed;
                });
              }
```

`pressed = !pressed` - Is the same as saying pressed is equal to what pressed is currently not. So on press it will switch to true if boolean is false, and false if boolean is true.

Comment: Didn't worked for me It says `Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null`

Comment: You need to create a boolean named pressed in the class first, and assign it to either true or false. So that it is not null.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a widget using the same code above.

```
class IconToggleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isSelected;
  final Function onPressed;
  IconToggleButton({this.isSelected, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: IconButton(
        iconSize: 30.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        icon: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: isSelected == true
                ? Icon(FontAwesome.sort_name_up)
                : Icon(FontAwesome.sort_name_down)),
        onPressed: () {
          onPressed();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

Create a class variable

```
 bool isSelected = false;
```

Use the widget as following:

```
IconToggleButton(
                        isSelected: isSelected,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              isSelected = !isSelected;
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      )
```

Hope that it will help many.